# php extract function cause memory exhausted when running on IIS

Tags: php, memory, iis-6

i got a very strange problem with my code running on PHP 5.2.8 + IIS6 ISAPI virtual host.

the page reports error "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 536870912 bytes)" when i'm using the following code.

```
$comments = $Comment_Model->getComments(2, $logid, 'n', $commentPage);
extract($comments);
```

but if i'm not using the "$comments" to extract, no error reports.

```
extract($Comment_Model->getComments(2, $logid, 'n', $commentPage));
```

what i have tried:

1. increase more memory by adding ini_set('memory_limit', '') into my script, not works.
2. move the script to other servers, it works.

it looks like an environment problem, does anyone has a clue?

Comment: In what way does increasing memory not work?

Comment: Can you enclose the script for getComments? (Between, you already using more than 500Mb, I dun think is normal)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with ini_set() not working for upping the memory limit on my shared hosting.  Depending on your server's setup, some ini options are not allowed to be changed via ini_set().
You may have to edit the php.ini file, which some hosting providers will allow, and some not.  I would also suggest that you make sure your script really should need that much memory (not a problem with the code).
I hope that helps.